# How to convert UTF8 data from PostgreSQL to AL32UTF8 Oracle DB?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, dblink

I have a task to import some data from Postgres database to Oracle via dblink

The connection between Postgres and Oracle works good, but unfortunately, when I try read data from created view (in Oracle database), I spotted a problem with data encoding - special national characters (Polish).

Source Postgres database have a UTF8 encoding, but Oracle have a AL32UTF8

Postgres:

```
select server_encoding
-

UTF8
```

Oracle:

```
select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter like '%CHARACTERSET';
-

PARAMETER VALUE

NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
```

When I use command "isql -v" (on destination machine with Oracle database) and later "select * from table;", everything works good, but when I use this same select from Oracle database using dblink my data encoding is broken

For example:
from odbc: isql -v (this is good)
select * from table;

```
[ID][Name]
0,Warszawa
1,Kraków
2,Gdańsk
```

from oracle using dblink: (not good)

```
select * from table@dblink;

[ID][Name]
0,Warszawa
1,KrakĂłw
2,GdaĹsk
```

/etc/odbc.ini:

```
[ODBC Data Sources]

[Postgres_DB]
Description         = Postgres_DB
Driver              = /usr/lib64/psqlodbcw.so
DSN                 = Postgres_DB
Trace               = Yes
TraceFile           = /tmp/odbc_sql_postgresdb.log
Database            = database
Servername          = server
UserName            = user
Password            = secret
Port                = 5432
Protocol            = 8.4
ReadOnly            = Yes
RowVersioning       = No
ShowSystemTables    = No
ShowOidColumn       = No
FakeOidIndex        = No
SSLmode             = require
Charset             = UTF8
```

$ORACLE_HOME/hs/admin/initPostgres_DB.ora:

```
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = Postgres_DB
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL=DEBUG
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /usr/lib64/libodbc.so
HS_FDS_SUPPORT_STATISTICS = FALSE
HS_LANGUAGE=AL32UTF8
set ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini
```

I have installed these packages:

```
postgresql-libs.x8664 - 8.4.20-8.el69
postgresql-odbc.x8664 - 08.04.0200-1.el6
unixODBC.x8664 - 2.2.14-14.el6
unixODBC-devel.x86_64 - 2.2.14-14.el6
```

Please help me.. I need to have the correct data in Oracle..
Thank you very much

Comment: You cannot have `dblink` diesctly access an Oracle database. Please describe your setup in more detail. Why don't you use oracle_fdw? That should work for the use case.

Comment: I found a temporary solution, I just added convert('column_name','EE8ISO8859P2') for each column containing text. At the moment, all special characters are displaying correctly.

Comment: You are speaking in riddles, since you cannot access Oracle with dblink.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71660364/how-to-convert-utf8-data-from-postgresql-to-al32utf8-oracle-db

Comment: Using `convert('column_name','EE8ISO8859P2')` is most likely the wrong solution, it does not match to any of the parameters you provided. Perhaps it look ok, because your terminal uses ISO-8859-2 (or something similar) but it is certainly the wrong way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I would check environment variable NLS_LANG when starting the Oracle instance. If it is set wrong or not set at all funny things may happen when selecting Non US7ASCII content.
Try

`export NLS_LANG=American_America.AL32UTF8`

Actually, only the Transparant Gateway client needs that setting - maybe there is a special parameter for it. HS_LANGUAGE seems not to be the one ...